# Storing array as json in database using codeigniter php not working

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i am trying to store an array as json in database using codeigniter website like below:

```
$this->db->insert('orders', 
                array('orderstatus' => $orderstatus,  
                      'productname' => json_encode($product1)
                    )
    );
```

the array has values like below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [productname] => Couple Combo Sherwani
            [pimage] => _RJ_0149-min.jpg,_RJ_0342-min.jpg,_RJ_0115-min.jpg
            [jrp] => 6000
            [deposit] => 6000
            [size] => XL
            [duration] => 3
            [quantity] => 1
        )

)
```

the database looks like:

[image]
[image]
however in database the value is stored as below:

```
"Array"
```

can anyone please tell me what is wrong in here, thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us what is in `$product1`, a `print_r($product1);` for example

Comment: But why would you want to store what appears to be a name, so a single string, as a JSON String?

Comment: @RiggsFolly actually i want to store all the product info as json inside one field

Comment: **Why** would you use a relational database if you want to do this

Comment: @RiggsFolly its actually done in relational database, i need to fix only this thing

Comment: But putting all that information into a single field negates all the uses of a relational database

Comment: Can you show the schema for that `orders` table please

Comment: @RiggsFolly actually i dont have enough time and no other option, i need to store it in a single column and display when needed

Comment: Ok, so the column is large enough, so try `'productname' => json_encode($product1[0])` is woudl be tidier than having the zero occurance as part of the JSON anyway

Comment: @RiggsFolly let me check

Comment: Although an INT(255) makes absolutely NO SENSE

Comment: @RiggsFolly But what if the table grows to 10^255 rows? (just kidding - I know what the INT argument means)

Comment: @BillKarwin I know, if anyone does you do.

Comment: @RiggsFolly i get value 'A' in database when i did json_encode($product1[0])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it works:

```
$products = [
    (object)[
        "name" => "Test product",
        "attribute1" => "Value1"
    ]
];

$this->db->table("orders")->insert([
    "name" => "Order for client",
    "info" => "Client want this order today",
    "products" => json_encode($products)
]); //In products column i have [{"name":"Test product","attribute1":"Value1"}]
```